# How to get Column Value of a DataRow in a Datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datatable, datarow

I have a `DataTable` which is bind to dataGridview in my code.

When I get datas from database, the gridview works fine. it fills with data.
What I want to do is getting the primary key value of the specified row.

Ex:

```
PK         Address          Phone
1          xxxyyyzzz...     1234567   
2          aaabbbccc...     2345678
```

What I want is this. User will click on any row, then click on a button to add some stuff.
Then I will get PK value, and do other stuffs.

How can I do it?

Comment: Just to note: the index of a datarow is not the value of the pk, maybe in your special case but it would be different at the latest when you delete records or change the order. **What do you mean with: "of the specified row"?**

Comment: When you select the data from the database, aren't you selecting the pk column as well before populating the datatable?

Comment: @TimSchmelter
Hi Tim. Yes I know, What i need is the specified row's PK value.

Comment: @Icarus I editted the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm can you specify how and when you are talking about getting this value?

You can do this:

```
int index = dt.Rows.IndexOf(row);
```

But I am not sure what the point of that would be, if you already have the specified row, why can't you just get the PK via `row[columnName]`?

But this is more resource intensive than just looping through with a for loop.

Do you need this before or after binding to the dataGridView? If you need to get the value from the dataGridView row that is different.

**For your edit:**

You would can get the selected row like so:

```
if (yourDataViewGrid.SelectedRows.Count == 1) 
{ 
Int pk = yourDataViewGrid.Rows[yourDataViewGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells["PK"].Value.ToString(); 
}
```

If you are doing it by some other method like using a checkbox to select a row, you would do this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in YourDataGridView.Rows)
        {

            if ((Boolean)((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["CheckBoxName"]).FormattedValue)
            {
               Int pk = rows.Cells["PK"].Value.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Hi DOTang.
Yes I've changed my question.
Yes, I need to get the value from the datagridview.

Answer (score 2):

The DataGridView control binds to a DataTable using the DataView class.  You can use something like this to get the DataRow of a DataGridViewRow

```
var vrow = (DataRowView)grid.Rows[12].DataBoundItem; // get the bound object
var drow = vrow.Row; // the Row property references the real DataRow
```

where 12 is the index you are looking for.  Sometimes it helps to set the DataSource property to a DataView explicitly and keep a reference to it on your form.  The view will know the sorting of the data too

```
var view = new DataView(table);
grid.DataSource = view;
```